# How to handle the "Could Not Load SSL Library" error in Delphi 7 when Posting JSON Data

Tags: json, openssl, delphi-7, 32-bit, indy10

I'm using Delphi 7, with Indy Components 10.0.52 and lkJSON 1.07
My syntax is like this:

```
  JSONObj := TlkJSONobject.Create;
  JSONObj.Add('data', JSONArray);
  JSONObj.Add('access_key', xAccessKey);

  JSONString := TlkJSON.GenerateText(JSONObj);

  RequestBody := TStringStream.Create(JSONString);
  try
    SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

    HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    HTTP.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
    try
      ResponseText := HTTP.Post(xAlamatWEB, RequestBody); //{Error "Could Not Load SSL Library" }
      ShowMessage(ResponseText);
    finally
      HTTP.Free;
    end; 
  finally
    RequestBody.Free;
  end;
```

Please help, how to handle it?

Note: I have installed OpenSSL 32 bit, have also set the Path in Windows, and have also copied libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll into System32.

I am trying to create a data sending application using JSON and I also hope to be successful in doing it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You are using extremely old versions of both Delphi and Indy. Can you upgrade? At the very least, you should upgrade Indy to the latest version, which still supports Delphi 7. In any case, the OpenSSL DLLs should be put in your application's folder, not the System32 folder. Also, you did not say which version of the DLLs you are using exactly. `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` supports up to OpenSSL 1.0.2u. What does Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function report after the error occurs?